# Sorting an array by data types using native Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

please suggest elegant ways to sort an array by data types.
For example, sorting the following array:

```
testArray = ["1", "5", 4 , 8, [1,2,3], {test:"test"}, [1,3,4], {test2:"test2"}, 6, "test"]
```

to appear like that:

```
["1", "5", "test", 4, 6, 8, [1,2,3], [1,3,4], {test:"test"}, {test2:"test2"}]
```

The actual order of the datatypes doesn't really matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to worry about certain edge cases like `undefined` and `null`, you could use `value.constructor.name`.

This will sort values by type `"Array"`, `"Number"`, `"Object"`, `"String"`, in that order:

```js
const input = ["1", "5", 4 , 8, [1,2,3], {test:"test"}, [1,3,4], {test2:"test2"}, 6, "test"];
const sorted = input.sort((a, b) => (a.constructor.name).localeCompare(b.constructor.name));

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```